# Python exit codes

Tags: python, unix

Where can I find information about meaning of exit codes of "python" process on Unix? For instance, if I do "python thisfiledoesntexist.py", I get exit code 2

Summary:

```
from errno import errorcode
print errorcode[2]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated, mostly the error codes come from the executed script and `sys.exit()`.

The example with a non-existing file as an argument to the interpreter fall in a different category. Though it's stated nowhere I would guess, that these exit codes are the "standard" Linux error codes. There is a module called [`errno`](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html) that provides these error numbers (the exit codes come from `linux/include/errno.h`.

I.e.: `errno.ENOENT` (stands for for "No such file or directory") has the number 2 which coincides with your example.

Comment: I had several errno.h files, none of of which had paths ending in "linux/include/errno.h". I started with "/usr/include/linux/errno.h" as the most similar, and then followed C include statements to "/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h" before finding error code 2 ("No such file or directory"), though the one before that  ("usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h") had higher error numbers.

Answer (score 8):

The Python manual states this regarding its exit codes:

> Some systems have a convention for assigning specific meanings to specific exit codes, but these are generally underdeveloped; Unix programs generally use 2 for command line syntax errors and 1 for all other kind of errors.

So, since you specified `thisfiledoesntexist.py` as a command line argument, you get a return code of 2 (assuming the file does not, in fact, exist. In that case I'd recommend renaming it to `thisfiledoesexist.py`. `;)` )

Other that such parsing errors, the return code is determined by the Python program run. 0 is returned unless you specify another exit code with `sys.exit`. Python itself does not interfere.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe exit code constants from [os module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.EX_OK) can help you. Also have a look at [sys.exit](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no 100% guarantee that Python's exit codes will be what [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.EX_OK) claims they will be: *[os._exit](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os._exit)* allows the Python programmer to define which exit code is supposed to be used, which means `python file_exists_but_claims_that_it_does_not.py` could exit with `os.EX_DATAERR`.

Comment: on my Ubuntu system, it seems to return codes from `errno`, not sure what `os` codes are for, but assign different meanings to the same numeric values than the `errno` module