# Why does php function exec() return status code 2

Tags: php

I am trying to run a simple python script from within my php application.

For test purposes, here is my code:

```
function run()
{
    $result = exec('python3.7 testPy.py',$output, $return_code); 
    dd($result, $output, $return_code); //dd() is alias for dump and die. 
} 
run();
```

testPy.py:

```
print('Ok')
```

if I run this command via console as root I get the following output:

```
root@xxx:Controller$ python3.7 testPy.py 
Ok
```

The same thing is with the www-data user:

```
www-data@xxx:Controller$ python3.7 testPy.py 
Ok
```

How ever, if call my php script via browser, I get the following output:

```
run.php on line 3: "" 
run.php on line 3: []
run.php on line 3: 2
```

run.php and testPy.py are in the same folder.

Any ideas are very welcome.

Comment: change to `print('Ok')` ?

Comment: Thank for noticing, was copy paste error when preparing for this post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python exit codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758514/python-exit-codes)

Comment: Try `$result = exec('python3.7 ./testPy.py',$output, $return_code);`

Comment: No result change.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed on some hosting servers the exec function in php is disabled by default.
Check your phpinfo()

or

```
if(function_exists('exec')) {
    echo "exec is enabled";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in php file

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python testPy.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```