# pdflatex is not installed in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, pdflatex

I'm trying to use [lcapy's](https://www.google.com/search?q=lcapy&oq=lcapy&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39j35i19i39j69i59j69i60l4.1424j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) python library to draw some electrical circuits in google colab. Unfortunately, I'm always getting an error:

`RuntimeError: pdflatex is not installed`

Even though I did `pip install pdflatex`
I couldn't find anything related to this error in lcapy's docs.

the notebook can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KLpNLekwXLnP8xUfAUeGn1g42vugFA2N?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think that some permission with you notebook is wrong, I can't open it. Anyway, are you sure pdflatex has been installed correctly? Did you do `pip install pdflatex`? It seems to be installed correctly in my Colab

Comment: updated the link. and yes, I did ```pip install pdflatex```. it looks like colab does not recognize this library.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar issue/error trying to render PDFs from latex output generated by pandas in google colab recently.  The error I got was complaining about a file ([Error Code 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758514/python-exit-codes/6758687)), listed 'pdflatex' as the missing file, but I confirmed the install had completed as you reported.  This led me to realize there were missing LaTex dependencies that were generating the error; the traceback seemed a bit misleading to me. Here is the solution that worked for me:

First, install components and dependencies in colab notebook:

```python
!pip install folium==0.2.1
!pip install pdflatex
!sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended 
!sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra
!sudo apt install dvipng
```

In my first attempt, There was an error buried in the install of `pdflatex` with an incompatible version of `folium 0.8.x`, so the first command rolls it back to the compatible version from the error trace.  Probably not totally necessary to roll back folium, but I haven't tested.

The latex install commands were shamelessly lifted from [this answer for latex-equations-do-not-render-in-google-colaboratory-when-using-matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55746749/latex-equations-do-not-render-in-google-colaboratory-when-using-matplotlib), where they offer a bit more explanation.  The whole install process produced quite a bit of output and took some time.

After completed, I was able to generate a pdf file from my LaTex string similar to the [example from the package docs](https://pypi.org/project/pdflatex/):

```python
import pdflatex as ptex

pdfl = ptex.PDFLaTeX.from_texfile(r'/content/my_tex_string_file.tex')
pdf, log, completed_process = pdfl.create_pdf()
with open('testPDF.pdf', 'wb') as pdfout:
        pdfout.write(pdf)
```

`my_tex_string_file.tex` was generated from pandas in my test case, and I added a preamble manually (string concatenation) to include the correct latex packages for my desired output, but a quick look through the github page for [lcapy](https://github.com/mph-/lcapy) shows the same approach may work for lcapy as well.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue myself and after verifying pdflatex is installed with `!pdflatex -help`, I looked into Lcapy's code. The easiest workaround I found is to comment out line 73 of system.py. I only need schematic tools, so this solution is adequate for me. If you need a proper solution, all the relevant functions are in the same file and it seems that `import pdflatex` is unnecessary as the library searches for the binary.